# How to reset myPHPadmin (mySql) password on MYCloud EX2 Ultra (Linux Armada 4.14.22-armada-18.09.3)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I forgot the root password for MySQL server on my MYCloud EX2 Ultra (4.14.22-armada-18.09.3)

When logging in here:

- http:///phpMyAdmin/index.php

I get:

- mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using
  password: YES)

And within etc:

I can find my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
user = test
password = test1234
```

I've tried adding the user and password here but no success.  Anyone have any idea on how to get this password reset?

Comment: [u: admin, p: admin](https://community.wd.com/t/mysql-on-ex2/98147/3) is the default. The configuration file under `[mysqld]` doesn't store the user credentials, remove as `user` refers to the unix user it should run as. Use `skip-grant-tables` in the config file, restart the device. and then after login; `flush privileges;  alter user test@localhost identified by 'test1234'` [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

**Stop the MySQL Server:**

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

**Start MySQL in Safe Mode:**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

**Access MySQL without Password:**

```
mysql -u root
```

**Use the MySQL Database:**

```
use mysql;
```

**Update the Password:**

```
update user set authentication_string=password('NEW_PASSWORD') where user='root';
```

Replace NEW_PASSWORD with your desired password.

**Flush Privileges:**

```
flush privileges;
```

**Exit MySQL:**

```
exit;
```

**Stop MySQL Safe Mode:**

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

**Start MySQL Normally:**

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Now you should be able to login with the new password. Ensure to replace NEW_PASSWORD with the actual password you want to set.

Comment: When running  sudo mysql stop, I get:

    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)